# React, unable to display the data received by an api, after doing a GET in componentDidMount()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have done a function in my react call which calls an api, and sets a state based on the data received by that api

```
getUserList() {
    API.get('/userlist')
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({
                userList: response.data
            }, () => {
                console.log(this.state.userList) //I can see this
            });
        })
}
```

This is how my constructor looks

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        retracted: false,
        userList: []

    }
    this.getUserList = this.getUserList.bind(this);
}
```

I call it in componentDidMount()

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.getUserList();
}
```

But then my render crashes, because both console.log return undefined

```
render() {
    var users = this.state.userList;
    var user = users[0].email //cannot read email of undefined

    console.log(this.state.userList)
    console.log(users)
    return (
        <div class="maincontainer">
            <div className="content-landing">
                 <p>{user}</p> 
            </div>

        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: is it necessary to call `this.getUserList = this.getUserList.bind(this);` in constructor, did you checked removing `this.getUserList = this.getUserList.bind(this);` this form constructor ??

Comment: @AkhilAravind that is how you define functions as far as i know, bt anyway it wont change anyting removing it, sam error

Comment: On the first cycle, userList is empty because the result is not fetched yet, so users[0] is undefined. Consider `if (this.state.userList) {do rendering} else { display loading component }`

Comment: Use arrow function getUserList = ()=> { ...... }

Comment: console the response first. look what you get in the console.

Comment: @AllenBert theres no difference in using or not using arrow functions, and in both cases i receive a proper response, which is an array of data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`componentDidMount` is not `async`, and cannot be. You should deal with transition state like `loading` during the async call.

Consider do a check since the result is not fetched yet :

```js
    render() {
      var users = this.state.userList;

      if (users.length === 0) {
        return <p>loading</p>
      }

      return <p>{users[0].email}</p>
    }
```

This could be not fully fonctionnal depending your usage, especially for error response. You still do a check for `error` case / state where `users.length === 0` but not `loading`.

Comment: this works, as I alreayd told to the other user, altho it seems strange to me having to do a check for that. I thought that componentDidMount was supposed to finish the fetching , since the API.get is async, and onl after the finishing it would let the render execute. But thanks anyway

Comment: Ok I'll edit to explain, but `componentDidMount` will not wait your async function. And it still a good behaviour to have a catch for loading / error states. If you want your component to WAIT the result it's another question :)

Comment: As a sample I made a codesandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-wilbur-e1bb0 . You can see the console to check the calls in cycles.

Answer (score 1):

```
var user = users[0].email //cannot read email of undefined
```

this code is the culprit. because on the first render is empty.

can you try a null check before accessing users[0].email heres an example

```
var user = users.length > 0 ? users[0].email : ""
```

Answer (score 1):

this is a case of initially undefined data, until there is data in users this line `var user = users[0].email` will crash because its trying to access non existing data so rewrite that part into:

```js
var user = users && users[0] ? users[0].email : null
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with Axios, please find below code snippet, as setting the state will result in render to execute:

```
var self = this;
axios.get('/url')
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
  self.setState({userList: response.data})
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Im using axios, API.get is an axios instance, and the point is that its setting the state , i can see it in the setState callback